# Modern list web part - voting field does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-webpart

I've created a list and added a voting option (found under the Ratings settings). Users now see a heart-shaped icon depicting the number of likes a list item received and can vote on it. This works as expected in the full list view.

We're now seeing an issue, however, when visualizing the list using a list web part on a modern page. Now, attempting to click on the heart-shaped icon doesn't work - the item is selected instead, which I don't need or want. Unchecking the checkbox option under "tabular items" does not seem to affect this behavior.

I'm at a lost as to how to fix this, nothing appears in the browser's console either when attempting to like. Do we have to abandon web parts in this case?